# how to create moving background using cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a game where I need to keep my background moving. Like in game [canabalt](http://www.canabalt.com).

I am developing this game on ios platform. can i do this using cocos2d? if yes how to do it?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have did this by using [Ray's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) on game development.

i introduced various objects in background and positioned them on time interval.